# Scala specific -- does an immutable.Set consume significantly more memory than a mutable.Set?

Tags: scala, set, immutability, oom

Using Scala 2.12.8 on Java Hotspot 17.0.1, have a large number of instances of an object which contains code like this:

```
var tmpSet[SomeType] = mutable.Set[SomeType]()
lazy val finalSet[SomeType] = { val tmp = tmpSet.toSet; tmpSet = null; tmp }
```

During initialization, the logic builds the tmpSet in all of the objects. Then runs this:

```
for(i <- 0 until numberOfInstances ) instance(i).finalSet.size
```

to force the conversion to an immutable.Set which will be used for all further processing.

Before the conversion, using an -Xmx14G parameter, about 4.5G of memory has been consumed (for all the tmpSet's). Running the conversion always throws OOM. Have placed traces of memory use at points within the for(...) loop and can see memory usage steadily increasing until the OOM.

Any idea what is happening here? Even if the GC is disabled and does not recover any of the tmpSet instances that have been set to null, there should still be enough RAM -- unless an immutable.Set takes far more memory than the equivalent mutable.Set.

WITHDRAWING this question. Wrote a testbed (below as an answer) to mimic this situation and it does NOT show this behaviour -- so must be some other problem within my codebase.

Comment: You could consider using a builder (`Set.newBuilder`) instead of a mutable set in order to build immutable sets.

Comment: You should show more code: how the sets are actually built. Where and how the memory usage is measured. 
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Testbed code to mimic the situation, and it does **not** exhibit the problem.
**Note** Had trouble pasting the code with some special symbols. In particular replaced < with & lt ; to keep the HTML happy (about line 16). Also increased the indent.

```
    /** Test case to explore OOM issue when converting a large number of mutable.Set's to immutable.Set's
     *  The 'lazy val finalSet' logic converts each mutable.Set into an immutable.Set, releasing the mutable.Set in the process.
     *
     *  The original expectation was that this would consume roughly the same amount of memory as before the conversion!!!
     **/
    import scala.collection.mutable
    import scala.collection.immutable
    
    case class TestSetOOM(numStrings:Int) {
      import TestSetOOM._
      // tmpSet is loaded with sizeOfSet unique strings when this class is initialized
      var tmpSet:mutable.Set[String]        = mutable.Set[String]()
      // finalSet is an immutable.Set initialized when finalSet.size is invoked. tmpSet is converted, and then released
      lazy val finalSet:immutable.Set[String] = { val tmp = tmpSet.toSet; tmpSet = null; tmp}
      // Executes at initialization
      for(i <- 0 until numStrings) tmpSet += getString
    }
    
    object TestSetOOM {
      /////// The basic parameters controlling the tests ////////
      val numInstances = 10000      // How many instances of TestSetOOM to create
      val sizeOfString = 1000       // How large to make each test string (+ 16 for the number)
      val sizeOfSet    = 1000       // How many test strings to add to the 'tmpSet' within each instance
      val gcEveryN     = 1000       // During the conversion phase, request a GC & pause every N instances processed
                                    // NOTE: Would REALLY love to have a method to FORCE a complete, deep GC for use
                                    //       in exactly test routines such as this!!!
      val pauseMillis  = 100        // Number of milliseconds to pause during the gdEveryN, can be zero for no pause
                                    // The hope is that if we pause the main thread then the JVM may actually run the GC
      val reportAsMB   = true       // True == show memory reports as MB, false as GBs
      //////// ... end of basic parameters ... ////////
      val baseData     = numInstances.toLong * sizeOfSet * (sizeOfString + 16)
    
      def main(ignored:Array[String]):Unit = {
        var instances:List[TestSetOOM] = Nil    // Create numInstances and prepend to this list
    
        for(i  0) Thread.sleep(pauseMillis)
    
        ln("")
        ln(f"Instances: $numInstances%,d, Size Of mutable.Set: $sizeOfSet%,d, Size of String: ${sizeOfString + 16}%,d ==          ${MBorGB(baseData)} base data size")
        ln("")
        ln(s"             BASELINE -- $memUsedStr -- after initialization of all test data")
    
        var dummy = 0L
        var cnt   = 0
        instances.foreach { item =>
          dummy     += item.finalSet.size       // Forces the conversion
          cnt       += 1
          if(gcEveryN > 0 && (cnt % gcEveryN) == 0){
            runtime.gc
            if(pauseMillis > 0) Thread.sleep(pauseMillis)
            ln(f"$cnt%,11d converted -- $memUsedStr ")
          }
        }
        ln("")
        ln(s"                FINAL -- $memUsedStr")
      }
      val runtime      = Runtime.getRuntime
      // Get a memory report in either MBs or GBs
      def memUsedStr = {  val max = runtime.maxMemory
                          val ttl   = runtime.totalMemory
                          val free  = runtime.freeMemory
                          val used  = ttl - free
                          s"Memory -- Max: ${MBorGB(max)}, Total: ${MBorGB(ttl)}, Used: ${MBorGB(used)}"
                        }
      def MBorGB(amount:Long) = { val amt = amount / (if(reportAsMB) 1000000 else 1000000000L)
                                  val as  = if(reportAsMB) "MB" else "GB"
                                                f"$amt%,9d $as"
                                              }
      // Generate strings with leading unique numbers as test data so the compiler cannot
      // recognize as equal and memoize just one if they were all the same!
      val emptyString   = "X" * sizeOfString
      var numString     = 0L
      def getString     = { numString += 1
                            f"${numString}%,16d$emptyString"
                          }
    
      def ln(str:String) = println(str)
    }
```

**Output of execution**
Instances: 10,000, Size Of mutable.Set: 1,000, Size of String: 1,016 ==             10,160 MB base data size

```
         BASELINE -- Memory -- Max:    15,032 MB, Total:    15,032 MB, Used:    10,746 MB -- after initialization of all test data
  1,000 converted -- Memory -- Max:    15,032 MB, Total:    15,032 MB, Used:    10,783 MB 
  2,000 converted -- Memory -- Max:    15,032 MB, Total:    15,032 MB, Used:    10,825 MB 
  3,000 converted -- Memory -- Max:    15,032 MB, Total:    15,032 MB, Used:    10,867 MB 
  4,000 converted -- Memory -- Max:    15,032 MB, Total:    15,032 MB, Used:    10,909 MB 
  5,000 converted -- Memory -- Max:    15,032 MB, Total:    15,032 MB, Used:    10,951 MB 
  6,000 converted -- Memory -- Max:    15,032 MB, Total:    15,032 MB, Used:    10,992 MB 
  7,000 converted -- Memory -- Max:    15,032 MB, Total:    15,032 MB, Used:    11,034 MB 
  8,000 converted -- Memory -- Max:    15,032 MB, Total:    15,032 MB, Used:    11,076 MB 
  9,000 converted -- Memory -- Max:    15,032 MB, Total:    15,032 MB, Used:    11,117 MB 
 10,000 converted -- Memory -- Max:    15,032 MB, Total:    15,032 MB, Used:    11,158 MB 

            FINAL -- Memory -- Max:    15,032 MB, Total:    15,032 MB, Used:    11,162 MB
```